# Show only one icon in one common headerbar in angularjs and ionic-v1

Tags: html, css, angularjs, tabs, ionic-v1

I have an application using Angularjs and Ionic-v1.

I have a common headerbar where i have 2 icons(one for Tab1 and one for Tab2).
And in the bottom of the screen i have 2 tabs(Tab1 and Tab2).

When i am in Tab1,i want to show icon for Tab1 only.And when I am in Tab2 i want to show icon for Tab2 only.

```
<div  ng-click="menu.changeLayout()">
                    <a class="icon_one"  ng-if="!grid"></a>
                    <a class="icon_change"  ng-if="grid"></a>
                    <a class="icon_one_test" ng-if="!grid1"></a>
                    <a class="icon_change_test"  ng-if="grid1"></a>
                </div>



In this line   <a class="icon_one_test" ng-if="!grid1"></a> ,Is there any way to hide icon_one and icon_change class?Or is there any other way to do this.
```

Angular code

```
$rootScope.grid=false;
$rootScope.grid1=false;


menu.changeLayout=function(){
    console.log("current state"+$state.current.name);
    if($state.current.name=='menu.tab1'){
        console.log('tab1');
        $rootScope.grid=!$rootScope.grid;
    }
    else if($state.current.name=='menu.tab2'){
        console.log('tab2');
        $rootScope.grid1=!$rootScope.grid1;
    }

}
```

How to achieve this.Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-class` to set the classes according to conditions.

```
<div  ng-click="menu.changeLayout()">
       <a ng-class="{icon_one: !grid , icon_change: grid}" ></a> 
       <a ng-class="{icon_one_test: !grid , icon_change_test: grid}" ></a>  
</div>
```

inside the condition hide the unselected tabs also.

```
 if($state.current.name=='menu.tab1'){
        console.log('tab1');
        $rootScope.grid= true;
        $rootScope.grid1 = false;
    }
    else if($state.current.name=='menu.tab2'){
        console.log('tab2');
        $rootScope.grid1=true;
        $rootScope.grid= false;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this but still 2 icons are showing.@Sachila Ranawaka

Comment: Yes,this also i tried,still 2 icons are coming.@Sachila Ranawaka

Comment: can u create a plnkr