# How to get current state in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using like this in my .html file,but it is not working.

```
 <p>State is {{state.current.name}}</p>
```

In controller.js i am able to get it.
But I want to get it in html file.
Anyone can help me in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in controller assign state to a variable

```
$scope.state = $state;
```

Now you can access it in the HTML.

```
<p>State is {{state.current.name}}</p>
```

Make sure to inject `$state` into controller.

Comment: Thank You @Sachila Ranawaka .It is working.
Can you please look into below link and help me out how to do this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020325/show-only-one-icon-in-one-common-headerbar-in-angularjs-and-ionic-v1